# Company A disappointed me. Can I say I "turned to competition", meaning I went to Company B?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

I know I could say it otherwise, I am just curious about the proper usage in this context:

I bought a bad product from Company A. I want to say that next time I am going to shop elsewhere. Can I say that I will "turn to competition"? To me it sounds a bit too much as "becoming"..

Comment: "Turn to **the** competition" would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

> "Turn to the competion / turn to the competitor"

To say that you want to change company/brand.